# AngularJS Filter (Function and input search together)

Tags: angularjs

I want to use filter function and input search at the same time by using AngularJS. I can able to do with multiple functions. But I'm getting some errors while I add an textbox for search. Is there any way to do this? I tried some ways but no one did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Example code is below

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []),
  url = "http://www.filltext.com/?rows=50&pretty=true&fName={firstName}&age=[18,19,20,21]";

app.controller("controller", function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get(url)
    .success(function(resp) {
      $scope.list = resp;
    });

  $scope.filterAge = function(item) {
    return item.age > 19;
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Filter</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="controller">
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in list | filter: filterAge">
          <td>{{ item.fName }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.age }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add custom filter to angular module instead adding filter function to your controller. This is the example:

**CustomFilter:**

```
.filter('filterByAge', function filterByAge() {
  return function(array, age) {
    var filteredArray = [];

    angular.forEach(array, function(item) {
      if (item.age > age) {
        filteredArray.push(item);
      }
    });

    return filteredArray;
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search..." />
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in list | filter: search | filterByAge:19">
      <td>{{ item.fName }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.age }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.$watch('search', function (data) {
    //sorting logic
})
```

Watcher is waiting for any action taken on search filed then the function is executed.